# Reverse array in C language

Tags: arrays, c

It is an reverse array program ,  but the output of program is getting wrong its not reversing all numbers I have dry run this code but am not getting where the issue is ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverseArray(int ar[], int start, int end)
{
    while (start < end)
    {   ar[start] = ar[start] + ar[end];
        ar[end] = ar[start] - ar[end];
        ar[start] = ar[start] - ar[end];
        start += 1;
        end -= 1;
        reverseArray(ar, start, end);
    }
  
}

void main()
{
    int ar[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    reverseArray(ar, 0, 4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", ar[i]);
    }
}
```

Output is : 5 2 3 4 1

> What I found that control is getting inside while loop  for 3 times
> but according to condition it should run the loop only for 2 times

Comment: It's incorrect to have both a loop and a recursive call. One is undoing the work of the other.

Comment: Why did you call `reverseArray` recursively? Trace out how the program flows from the start till the end (using a paper and a pen) and you will understand what is wrong with your code

Comment: I know its not a recursive approach in place of while loop I  should have given condition ie :  if(step == end) return; but I have dry run this code and  am not getting where it is   wrong

Comment: To know what is going wrong, you can print something before the recursive call of reverseArray() it will tell you how many times it is making the recursive call. Also you can print arr[start] and arr[end] values in the beginning of while loop. It will help you know.

Comment: You must have done dry run an idea of your code you have in your head. Instead, try dry run the code you have on a paper in front of you. I mean do each line of code exactly as it is written, not as you _intended_ it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already there are great answers provided by the experts..

I am trying to answer in my way.

Basically when `reverseArray(ar, start, end);` is called
start=1,end=3

Recursively calling `reverseArray(ar, start, end);`

reversed your array and returned control when start=2 end=2

But your first while loop hasn’t finished yet and undoing what you wanted to achieve.

Function call by value , by reference is playing the game here.

[image: dryrun]

You are passing reference of arr but for start and end you are passing value.

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing loop with recursion. Recursively, you reverse the subsection of your array and reverse it again with your loop. Only the outermost elements remain swapped.

By the way, swapping like this could be subject to overflows, resulting in undefined behaviour.

Comment: I know its not a recursive approach in place of while loop i  should have given condition is if(step == end) return;   but i have dry run this code am not getting where it is getting wrong

Comment: If you lay out the dry run on paper in the comments, we might see where the flaw in your thinking is. You could start like this: ar[0]=6 ar[4]=1 ar[0] =5 start=1 end=3

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add the function call at the end. If you want to add that, then you don't end to add the **while loop**,because by calling the function you are making it recursive. **Recursion and loops don't go well together**.

Also, try not to pass Hard-coded values in parameters, It isn't a good practice :)

Comment: I know its not a recursive approach in place of while loop I should have given condition ie : if(step == end) return; but I have dry run this code and am not getting where it is wrong

Comment: The main issue is that when your compiler reaches the function call in the while loop, it has values of start and end as 1and 3 respectively. then, you array is reversed due to the recursive nature of your function. when compiler returns from the recursive function. Your start and end still has values as 1 and respectively. Hence your while loop doesn't end.

Answer (score 1):

Due to having both a `while` loop and using recursive calls, your code is doing

```
reverseArray(ar, 0, 4)
    a[0] <-> a[4]  // swap
    reverseArray(ar, 1, 3)
        a[1] <-> a[3]  // swap
        reverseArray(ar, 2, 2)
    a[1] <-> a[3]  // swap
    reverseArray(ar, 2, 2)
```

so you swap element `ar[1]` and `ar[3]` twice, i.e. they end up in their original positions.

The solution seems simple: Just delete the recursive call.

Further:

**Don't swap elements by "smart code" like:**

```
    ar[start] = ar[start] + ar[end];
    ar[end] = ar[start] - ar[end];
    ar[start] = ar[start] - ar[end];
```

Write it simple and readable like:

```
    int tmp = ar[start];
    ar[start] = ar[end];
    ar[end] = tmp;
```

It's easier to read and understand, it's most likely faster and most important it avoids integer overflow (which is undefined behavior in C).

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you the issue.

Values when your program reaches the line

```
reverseArray(ar, start, end);
start = 1, end = 3, arr={5,2,3,4,1}
```

After this, your compiler goes into the function once again from where your array comes back completely reversed. But all this happen in some other while loop because you called the function once again. Hence when your compiler comes back from the function call.
Remember, your values of start and end in the first while loop will still be

```
Start = 1, end = 3
**But**
Your array is now arr = {5,4,3,2,1}
```

Your while loop runs again and that is why your first and last element isn't disturbed while your rest of the array is disturbed in final output.